# Creating indexed array from query in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I need to create the following array from a query in codeigniter. So far what I'm producing is not what I'm looking for.

What I need...

```
array (size=4)
  1 => string '1414277999' (length=10)
  2 => string '1470411334' (length=10)
  3 => string '1456617599' (length=10)
  4 => string '1461538799' (length=10)
```

What I currently have..

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[35]
      public 'session' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'end' => string '1477090799' (length=10)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[36]
      public 'session' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'end' => string '1481932799' (length=10)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[37]
      public 'session' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'end' => string '1488585599' (length=10)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[38]
      public 'session' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'end' => string '1493420399' (length=10)
```

This is my query in codeigniter..

```
$bd = $this->db->select('session, end')
    ->from('session_dates')
    ->where('end >=', $now)
    ->get();
return $bd->result();
```

Can someone point me in the direction of how to build my query to create the array I'm looking for?

Comment: if you had searched on google you would have found the `result_array` @ first result with this question : `codeigniter get array from query`

Comment: I did google and result_array does not return the results I indicated.

Comment: You'r right, mybad, then : return array_map(function($val){ return $val['end']; }, $bd->array_result());

Answer (score 1):

Although this is probably not the best way to achieve your goal, I made an object to array conversion function which I can share with you:

**function (throw this into a helper file or something)**

```
function object_to_array_recursive(&$o)
{
    if(is_object($o))
    {
        $o = (array)$o;
    }

    if(is_array($o) && count($o) > 0)
    {
        foreach($o as $k=>&$v)
        {
            object_to_array_recursive($v);
        }
        unset($v);
    }
}
```

**Use of function**

```
$my_db_result = $bd->result();
object_to_array_recursive($my_db_result);

return $my_db_result;
```

Since it accepts the parameter by reference, you will have to pass it a variable name because `object_to_array_recursive($bd->result());` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract all the data you need into a new array, and then return it.

**You can do this like the following :**

```
$getEnds = function($value){ return $value->end; };

return array_map($getEnds, $bd->result());
```

The `array_map` looping the given results, and apply on each value of it the function in first parameter. This function just return the `end` param from current object.

**You can also compress your code :**

```
return array_map(function($value){ return $value->end; }, $bd->result());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$bd = $this->db->select('session, end')
    ->from('session_dates')
    ->where('end >=', $now)
    ->get();
$result_array = array();
foreach ($bd->result() as $row){
    $result_array[$row->session] = $row->end;
}
return $result_array;
```